# How to remove all html tags except last 5?

Tags: javascript, html

I set a php/javascript chat for my site, the problem is that I want to show only the last 5 messages, and then the older ones after 5 must disappear. These messages are entered in the **pre** . How can this be done? This is all the code I am using

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    cometApi.start({node:"/", dev_id:/ })

    cometApi.subscription("simplechat.newMessage", function(event){
        $("#web_chat").append('<pre><b style="font-size:15px">'+HtmlEncode(event.data.name)+'</b>: '+HtmlEncode(event.data.text)+'</pre>')
    })
})

function HtmlEncode(s)
{
  var el = document.createElement("div");
  el.innerText = el.textContent = s;
  s = el.innerHTML;
  return s;
}


function send()
{
   var name = $('#name').val();
   var text = $('#text').val();

   $.ajax({
        url: "/fileadmin/chat/chat.php",
        type: "POST", 
        data:"text="+encodeURIComponent(text)+"&name="+encodeURIComponent(name)
   });
}
```

PHPCODE:

```
 $comet = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, "/");

    if(mysqli_errno($comet))
    {
        echo "Error:".mysqli_error($link);
    }

    $msg = Array( "name" => $_POST["name"], "text"  => $_POST["text"] );
    $msg = json_encode($msg);
    $msg = mysqli_real_escape_string($comet, $msg);

    $query = "INSERT INTO pipes_messages (name, event, message)" .
      "VALUES('simplechat', 'newMessage', '".$msg."')";

    mysqli_query($comet, $query); 

    if(mysqli_errno($comet))
    {
        echo "Error:".mysqli_error($comet);
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "ok";
    }
```

Comment: Is viable for you to use a for cycle to limit 5 cycles in the php?

Comment: yes @FrancescoFortin

Comment: I'm confused, you're talking about PHP but showing us JavaScript, do you have trouble limiting the messages rendered on the PHP side or when messages are appended using JavaScript?

Comment: So just return 5 rows from the api calls it is better, and reduce the server work, why return a full response to the client and the client cut the data down to 5 rows? Only ITA: se puoi fare in modo che la api in php ritorni solo lo stretto necessario quando viene chiamata risparmi risorse al server e in questo caso anche al client che deve ritagliare 5 righe da un possibile enorme array della chat.

Comment: @FrancescoFortin The recent 5 pre must remain, the old ones disappear!

Comment: If you want the most recent 5 we must now how you fetch the rows in the first place, what SQL query you use for example or whatever you use to store your messages.

Comment: Hi @Julianv.dBerkmortel I added the php code (not created by me)

Comment: What you added doesn't have anything to do with fetching (SELECT) the messages from the database, it only inserts them.

Comment: @Julianv.dBerkmortel I added all the code. I only have this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use a nifty little css selector and then remove them on every `newMessage` event like this:

```
cometApi.subscription("simplechat.newMessage", function(event){
    $("#web_chat").append('<pre><b style="font-size:15px">'+HtmlEncode(event.data.name)+'</b>: '+HtmlEncode(event.data.text)+'</pre>')
    $('#web_chat > pre:nth-last-child(n+6)').remove()
})
```